# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Application labels aren't unique, duplicates: account

Tags: python-3.x, django-allauth, django-1.10

Run error prompt:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Application labels aren't
>   unique, duplicates: account

### .

I have set up an "account" and now I'm prompted to repeat what I need to do to solve the above mistakes.

---

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # must APP
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    # must APP
    # weibo、github和weixin
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.weibo',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.github',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.weixin',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # APP
    'blog',
    'account',
    'password_reset',
    'article',

]

# django-allauth setting
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
# django admin django-allauth
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',

# `allauth` specific authentication methods, such as login by e-mail
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
)

# setting SITE_ID
SITE_ID = 1
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'username_email'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
```